# Loop without comparison n times in C

Tags: c++, c, loops

If I have a loop that I know needs to be executed n times is there a way to write a while (or for) loop without a comparison each time? If not is there a way to make a macro turn:

```
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   operation();
}
```

into:

```
operation();
operation();
operation();
operation();
operation();
```

P.S. This is the fastest loop I've come up with so far.

```
int i = 5;
while(i-- >= 0) {
   operation();
}
```

Comment: That's nothing you should be doing. Your compiler already unrolls loops if it's more effective.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It's going to take more space in the instruction cache, require more instruction decoding, and basically be worse. If it was better, wouldn't the compiler convert it for you? (Unless it's a piece of junk, in which case why are you using it?)

Answer (score 7):

A Sufficiently Smart Compiler will do this for you.  More specifically, optimizing compilers understand loop unrolling.  It's a fairly basic optimization, especially in cases like your example where the number of iterations is known at compile time.

So in short: turn on compiler optimizations and don't worry about it.

Answer (score 5):

The number of instructions you write in the source code is not strictly related on the number of machine instructions the compiler will generate.

Most compilers are smarter and in your second example can generate code like:

```
operation();
operation();
operation();
operation();
operation();
```

automatically because they detect that the loop will always iterate 5 times.

Also if you do a profiling-oriented optimization and a the compiler sees that a loop has tiny a body and a very high repeat count it may unroll it even for a generic number of iterations with code like:

```
while (count >= 5) {
    operation();
    operation();
    operation();
    operation();
    operation();
    count -= 5;
}
while (count > 0) {
    operation();
    count--;
}
```

This will make for large `count`s about one fifth of tests compared to the naive version.

If this is worth doing or not is something that only profiling can tell.

One thing you can do if you know for sure that the code needs to be executed at least once is to write

```
do {
    operation();
} while (--count);
```

instead of

```
while (count--) {
    operation();
}
```

The possibility that `count==0` is somewhat annoying for CPUs because requires in the code generated by most compilers an extra JMP forward:

```
    jmp test
loop:
    ...operation...
test:
    ...do the test...
    jne loop
```

the machine code for the `do { ... } while` version instead is simply

```
loop:
    ... opertion ...
    ... do the test...
    jne loop
```

Comment: You can unroll the last loop with: `switch(count) {case 4:operation();
case 3: operation();
case 2: operation();
case 1: operation();
}`

Answer (score 0):

both loops will do comparisons..

anyhow the compiler should identify the constant iteration and unroll the loop.

You could check that with gcc and the optimization flags (-O) and look at the generated code afterwards.

More important: 
Don't optimize unless there is significant reason to do!

Answer (score 0):

Once the C code is compiled, the while and for loops are converted to comparison statements in machine language, so there is no way to avoid some type of comparison with the for/while loops. You could make a series of goto and arithmetic statements that avoid using a comparison, but the result would probably be less efficient. You should look into how these loops are compiled into machine language using radare2 or gdb to see how they might be improved there.

Answer (score 0):

With template, you may unroll the loop (in the count is known at compile time) with something like:

```
namespace detail
{

    template <std::size_t ... Is>
    void do_operation(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        std::initializer_list<std::size_t>{(static_cast<void>(operation()), Is)...};
    }

}

template <std::size_t N>
void do_operation()
{
    detail::do_operation(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8308fbce619d7f6a)

but the compiler may already do that sort of optimization for normal loop.